# Configuring Windows 2003 server (localhost)

Tags: windows, php

I have purchased a [Go Daddy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_Daddy) Windows 2003 server. The problem is I can't access my site via localhost but it can be accessed via a URL. What should I look for?

Answer (score 1):

You can go to a command prompt and try to ping localhost. If that doesn't work, check \windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts and look for an entry for 127.0.0.1    (that's a tab space) localhost. If that isn't there, add it.

Answer (score 0):

Localhost refers to running on your personal computer and webserver.

If godaddy has the computer, you will have to either log on to the server (through ssh, vpn, or something similar) and then you can use localhost. Or you could use the URL for it, as you have said that work.

Comment: i am using remote connection(vpn) and on my server i am trying to use localhost

Answer (score 0):

The web host we use also won't resolve localhost reliably. Wherever you currently use localhost in your configs just replace it with 127.0.0.1 and all should be well.